Glitched ContextMenu on transparent List
I need a transparent List (because of some particular background) and a ContextMenu on each list item, iOS 17+.
The problem here is: when the list item's height is bigger than the list's one and has a
.listRowBackground(Color.clear)

modifier on it, on iPad I see the following glitch:
video:
https://imgur.com/cxSYUvI
Unfortunately, the bug is not present in previews or simulators (not sure about iPhone).
Demonstration
The issue is perfectly reproducible with the following simple code:
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var message = Array(0 ..< 200).map { _ in "SOME SOME SOME SOME" }.joined(separator: "\n")
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Text(message)
                .contextMenu {
                    Button {
                        // Some action
                    } label: {
                        Text("Some Action")
                    }
                }
                .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
        }
    }
}

What I tried
What I already tried:

using Color.white.opacity(0.01) instead of Color.clear
using custom ContextMenu preview (for some reason the size of the preview is completely wrong even for a simple Text)

